# Starting PHP Netbeans XDEBUG from a Javascript/Jquery file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 8.1 with XDEBUG to debug PHP code on my local WAMP server and it works fine. In addition I use on the client side JavaScript/Jquery code that has AJAX request to the PHP file and transfers to the PHP file several parameters.

I could not find a way how to start automatically Netbeans PHP debug session after the AJAX request sends parameters to the PHP file. I do not mind adding code to the JavaScript/Jquery code to make it happen.

Your help in this matter is highly appreciated. I tried various things and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this simple tool: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/marklets/

Then, when You will start a xdebug session, it should work with jquery as well.

Comment: Is this debugger invoked when the Jquery access the PHP file.when invoked, does it let me single-step from a previously set break point?

Comment: jQuey request on PHP side is seen in the same way as normal foreground http request. All you need to be sure is if XDEBUG session is active. Those marklets are using JS to set/unset correct cookies

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug` as parameter in your URL to PHP code. And this will start debug session in Netbeans IDE, as @Rafal Kozlowski  said in his comment Netbeans XDEBUG session must be active in Netbeans. Hope this works for you